# How can I access the PHP session from a Codeception acceptance test?

Tags: php, codeception

Is it possible to read PHP's session `$_SESSION` from a Codeception acceptance test Cest file?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/4362#issuecomment-311232426 the browser session runs in a different process than the tests, so it's not possible directly.

However, I found a workaround :-)

Idea: In the test, read the session `sess_` file (which was generated by the browser session) from the filesystem, and parse it. This works for read-access; haven't tried for write-access.

In the test:

```
$cookie = $I->grabCookie('PHPSESSID'); // according to php.ini: session.name
$sessionFile = file_get_contents(ini_get('session.save_path').'/sess_'.$cookie);
$session = self::unserialize_php($sessionFile);
codecept_debug($session); // $session is an array. Run Codeception with `--debug` to see it
```

The unserialize function is taken from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#108037

```
private static function unserialize_php($session_data) {
    $return_data = array();
    $offset = 0;
    while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
        if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
            throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
        }
        $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
        $num = $pos - $offset;
        $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
        $offset += $num + 1;
        $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
        $return_data[$varname] = $data;
        $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
    }
    return $return_data;
}
```

Requirements in `php.ini` (both are fulfilled by default):

- `session.save_handler = files`
- `session.serialize_handler = php`